# rake aborted! Don't know how to build task 'dbconsole'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

This is the very beginnings of a rails app.

I made the new app, switched to it's directory. There are no models. I ran rake db:migrate and then tried rake dbconsole, and got the error that is the title of the question.
Any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no '`rake dbconsole`'.  Maybe you meant '`rails dbconsole`'?